# Is it allowed to use jQuery $(this) selector twice in a function and in an included each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a list, which contents x columns of data. When clicking an edit button in a row, I want to set the html content of each column of this row, which has a name attribute into an array, which key is named by the columns name attributes value.

```
data['id']   = '123';
data['name'] = 'John Doe';
data['city'] = 'Arlington';
```

For that I'm starting a click event on the edit div. Inside this function I'm working with $(this) selector for setting up an each() loop over all elements having a name attribute.
Inside this loop I'm catching the names and values of each matched element with $(this) selector again.

So, my question: although it works - is it allowed to do it this way? Using $(this) for two different things inside the same function?
Is there a different way?

Here is my working example code

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on( "click", ".edit", function() {
      var data = {};
      
      $(this).closest('.row').children('div[name]').each(function() {
        //form_data.append($(this).attr('name'), $(this).html());
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).html();
      });
      
      $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
<div name="id">123</div>
<div name="name">John Doe</div>
<div name="city">Berlin</div>
<div class="edit">> edit <</div>
</div>
<br clear="all">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong, inside function (the `.each(function() {...}`) you have a new local `this`.

Comment: It is allowed as `this` changes in each scope, I would put it into a variable though as it can get confusing to read which can make maintenance harder

Answer (score 4):

> Is it allowed?

It works, so of course.

Depends on what you mean by "allowed".

- Is it confusing - perhaps.
- Can it cause problems - definitely.

(There are plenty of questions on SO with this or problems caused by this that confirm it causes problems).

Reusing variable names ('this' in this case) is common and is based on *scope*.

It's hard to tell if you have a bug because you actually wanted the ".edit" html or the ".edit" attr rather than the `div`, so you can remove that confusion by copying `this` to a variable:

```
$(document).on( "click", ".edit", function() {
  var data = {};
  var btn = $(this);  // the button that was clicked

  btn.closest('.row').children('div[name]').each(function() {

    // Do you mean the div or did you really mean the clicked button?
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).html();  

    var div = $(this);  // the child div

    // clearly not what is desired
    // `btn` variable referring to the outer `this`
    data[div.attr('name')] = btn.html();  

    // intention clear
    data[div.attr('name')] = div.html();  
  });

  $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

});
```

In this case, it's "clear" as you wouldn't use the btn html on all the data entries (or would you? I don't know your requirements...).  So "unlikely".

But it's easy to see how, in another scenario, you would want to refer to what was clicked `btn==this` inside the nested `.each`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on( "click", ".edit", function() {
      var data = {};
      var that = this; // trick here
      $(this).closest('.row').children('div[name]').each(function() {
        //form_data.append($(this).attr('name'), $(this).html());
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(that).html();// replace this = that if you want to get parent element
      });

      $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong, what you do is simply this

```js
function setDivs() {
  //form_data.append($(this).attr('name'), $(this).html());
  data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).html();
}

function docClick(){
    var data = {};
    $(this).closest('.row').children('div[name]').each(setDivs);
    $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
}

function docReady(){
  $(document).on( "click", ".edit", docClick)
}

$( document ).ready(docReady);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
<div name="id">123</div>
<div name="name">John Doe</div>
<div name="city">Berlin</div>
<div class="edit">> edit <</div>
</div>
<br clear="all">
<div id="result"></div>
```